# Running with lumbar spinal stenosis

Tags: running, injury, spine

I have Lumbar Spinal Stenosis as described in [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29416/ab-workout-with-lumbar-spinal-stenosis/29424).

Since my injury I have been using the elliptical machine, but sometimes I still dream of running.

Before my injury I usually ran either 2-3 miles at 7mph or short distances sprints as part of interval training, anywhere between 50-200m.

Is this kind of activity recommended in my condition?

Comment: If you have a condition, you should seek qualified help.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll echo Alec's comment.  If you've been diagnosed with spinal stenosis, you should seek the advice of a qualified therapist.  Additionally, you may wish to get another opinion and an MRI as x-rays are not the best indicator of spinal stenosis:

> The X-rays can show the doctor various signs associated with spinal
>   stenosis, including loss of the normal intervertebral disc height, the
>   presence of bone spurs (osteophytes), and spinal instability (abnormal
>   motion between the vertebrae). The ultimate diagnosis of lumbar spinal
>   stenosis is made by an MRI scan (magnetic resonance imagining scan)
>   or CT scan (CAT scan or computerized axial tomography). These are more
>   advanced tests that are used to visualize the nerves in the lower back
>   and detect if they are being compressed from lumbar spinal stenosis. 
>   (http://www.medicinenet.com/lumbar_stenosis/page4.htm)

However, having said that, and, as someone who has had prior experience with your condition, I can offer you some advice.  I would caution you to not be overly aggressive in your recovery.  As I commented in your [previous question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29416/ab-workout-with-lumbar-spinal-stenosis/29424), spinal stenosis is a generic term for the narrowing of the spinal canal.  It typically presents as a [herniated, or, bulging disc](http://www.spine-health.com/conditions/herniated-disc/whats-a-herniated-disc-pinched-nerve-bulging-disc).  The disc protrudes into the spinal canal thus causing nerve root compression.  The resulting symptoms can be debilitating.

In my experience, running would typically be contraindicated in your present condition because the force exerted on your spine would further add to any existing spinal compression.  I would suggest you seek less aggressive exercises like swimming, or walking.  Additionally, if you haven't already started a therapeutic stretching program, that's something you should consider under the guidance of a physical therapist.